# Generating unique ID for different strings?

Tags: c#, string, hash, uniqueidentifier

I am trying to find a way to generate a unique id for a string. After generating that unique id, i must be able to get my string back, just by using that id.

String s = "This is the string";

After a sequence of code i would get a string uniqueID

And finally by using this uniqueID, i should get my s String back ("This is the string").

Any ideas on how to solve this?

I tried solving this with String.GetHashCode, but i encountered the warning from msdn:

> There is not a unique hash code value for each unique string value. Different strings can return the same hash code.

!Observation: I want to use this code sequence on longer strings. (Say 1000 words or more)

Comment: Given the constraints you mention (ie. none), I would just use the string.

Comment: Can you explain the *problem* you are trying to solve, instead of your "solution"?

Comment: What do you man by "getting back"? Look up in a dictionary? Or should the transformation be reversible? And what type does the unique id have?

Comment: `return s` returns a unique value and is easily reversible. Sounds like it's what you need.

Comment: Yes i can. I am trying to create a application, that encodes different strings(User input) using different encrypting algorythms. This "solution" would be one of those algorythms.

Comment: So your question is really "how can I encrypt a string?"... Why didn't you just say that?

Comment: Lol, no xD I was looking for a way to generate unique id's for different strings... the way i want to use them is a different story

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could possible use Base64?

Take a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524.aspx

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var encoded = Base64Encode("test string");
    var decoded = Base64Decode(encoded);
}

static string Base64Encode(string text)
{
    var bytes = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
    return System.Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);            
}

static string Base64Decode(string encodedText)
{
    var bytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(encodedText);
    return System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);            
}
```

Comment: What advantage is there to base 64 over just using the original string?

Comment: @KentBoogaart It's longer XD

Comment: +1 as it is one of possible valid encoding/encryptions. Also identity transform will give a bit shorter result :)

Comment: One advantage of using base64 rather than the original string is that you will know, no matter what, that the encoded string will be safe to store in a database (if that's the case). There will be better solutions sure, but this will work.

Comment: @Adam I should have specified "given the context of the question", wherein absolutely no requirements were stipulated. I could equally make up requirements that invalidate the B64 suggestion ;)